# Two urls pointing to one view with optional parameter

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have following view function:

```
@public_only
def homepage(request, signin=False):
    # function body
```

I want to point url / to this view:
I have in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^$',
    'homepage',
    name='homepage'),
```

I also want to point url `/signin` to the same view, but this one should set parameter `signin=True`.
I don't have idea, how to configure this in urls.py. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass extra arguments to your view functions like this:

```
url(r'^$', 'homepage', , {'signin': True}, name='homepage'),
url(r'^$', 'homepage', , {'signin': False}, name='signin'),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a third parameter in a URL pattern, which is a dict of arguments to pass straight to the view. So:

```
url(r'^signin/$',
    'homepage',
    {'signin': True},
    name='homepage'),
```

Comment: I dont think this gives the url pattern `/signin` that OP wants.

Comment: Sorry, meant to put "signin". Edited.

Comment: I like this solution, but Iam not sure how to use such passed dict. Could you explain it?

Comment: What? You don't need to use anything at all. That is simply passing the `signin` parameter as True, which is what you asked for.